# Odoo AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getppid' -- windows os.getppid

Tags: python, debugging, odoo

I am able to run Odoo v8 code in windows. But when I debug the code, the error occurs:

```
ppid = os.getppid()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getppid'
```

Environment:

Windows 7, eclipse, pydev, Odoo v8 code(latest code several days ago), debug mode.

Comment: For Python before version 3.2, `os.getppid()` is Unix only: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getppid, https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.getppid

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. You are right, mine is 2.7 and according to the document, getppid is not supported on windows.
But the code is open source and it is supported on windows and the python is specified to 2.7. Another strange thing is that when I run the code instead of debug the code, there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply uninstall *gevent* from your python packages

```
pip uninstall gevent
```

and you will be able to run your Odoo server in normal or debug mode.